# List Tables in a DolphinDB database

Tags: sql, database, dolphindb

What is the equivalent to **SHOW TABLES** in DolphinDB?

Answer (score 1):

I think in DolphinDB all functions to return summary information start with "get". For your question you can use "getTables".

Comment: what difference between listTables and  getTables